# Gson: How do I deserialize an inner JSON object to a map if the property name is not fixed?

Tags: gson

My client retrieves JSON content as below:

```
{
    "table": "tablename",
    "update": 1495104575669,
    "rows": [
        {"column5": 11, "column6": "yyy"},
        {"column3": 22, "column4": "zzz"}
    ]
}
```

In `rows` array content, the key is not fixed. I want to retrieve the key and value and save into a `Map` using Gson 2.8.x.

How can I configure Gson to simply use to deserialize?

Here is my idea:

```java
public class Dataset {

    private String table;
    private long update;
    private List<Rows>> lists; <-- little confused here.
       or private List<HashMap<String,Object> lists 

    Setter/Getter
}
```

```java
public class Rows {

    private HashMap<String, Object> map;

    ....
}

Dataset k = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, Dataset.class);
log.info(k.getRows().size()); <-- I got two null object
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson does not support such a thing out of box. It would be nice, if you can make the property name fixed. If not, then you can have a few options that probably would help you.

- Just rename the `Dataset.lists` field to `Dataset.rows`, if the property name is fixed, `rows`.
- If the possible name set is known in advance, suggest Gson to pick alternative names using the `@SerializedName`.
- If the possible name set is really unknown and may change in the future, you might want to try to make it fully dynamic using a custom `TypeAdapter` (streaming mode; requires less memory, but harder to use) or a custom `JsonDeserializer` (object mode; requires more memory to store intermediate tree views, but it's easy to use) registered with `GsonBuilder`.

For option #2, you can simply add the names of name alternatives:

```java
@SerializedName(value = "lists", alternate = "rows")
final List<Map<String, Object>> lists;
```

For option #3, bind a downstream `List<Map<String, Object>>` type adapter trying to detect the name dynamically. Note that I omit the `Rows` class deserialization strategy for simplicity (and I believe you might want to remove the `Rows` class in favor of simple `Map<String, Object>` (another note: use `Map`, try not to specify collection implementations -- hash maps are unordered, but telling Gson you're going to deal with `Map` would let it to pick an ordered map like `LinkedTreeMap` (Gson internals) or `LinkedHashMap` that might be important for datasets)).

```java
// Type tokens are immutable and can be declared constants

private static final TypeToken<String> stringTypeToken = new TypeToken<String>() {
};

private static final TypeToken<Long> longTypeToken = new TypeToken<Long>() {
};

private static final TypeToken<List<Map<String, Object>>> stringToObjectMapListTypeToken = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {
};

private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new TypeAdapterFactory() {
            @Override
            public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
                if ( typeToken.getRawType() != Dataset.class ) {
                    return null;
                }
                // If the actual type token represents the Dataset class, then pick the bunch of downstream type adapters
                final TypeAdapter<String> stringTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, stringTypeToken);
                final TypeAdapter<Long> primitiveLongTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, longTypeToken);
                final TypeAdapter<List<Map<String, Object>>> stringToObjectMapListTypeAdapter = stringToObjectMapListTypeToken);
                // And compose the bunch into a single dataset type adapter
                final TypeAdapter<Dataset> datasetTypeAdapter = new TypeAdapter<Dataset>() {
                    @Override
                    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Dataset dataset) {
                        // Omitted for brevity
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Dataset read(final JsonReader in)
                            throws IOException {
                        in.beginObject();
                        String table = null;
                        long update = 0;
                        List<Map<String, Object>> lists = null;
                        while ( in.hasNext() ) {
                            final String name = in.nextName();
                            switch ( name ) {
                            case "table":
                                table = stringTypeAdapter.read(in);
                                break;
                            case "update":
                                update = primitiveLongTypeAdapter.read(in);
                                break;
                            default:
                                lists = stringToObjectMapListTypeAdapter.read(in);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        in.endObject();
                        return new Dataset(table, update, lists);
                    }
                }.nullSafe(); // Making the type adapter null-safe
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) datasetTypeAdapter;
                return typeAdapter;
            }
        })
        .create();
```

```java
final Dataset dataset = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Dataset.class);
System.out.println(dataset.lists);
```

The code above would print then:

> [{column5=11.0, column6=yyy}, {column3=22.0, column4=zzz}]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'll try to follow your advice to solve my issue.